# Recurrence relation to extract coefficients $\frac{1}{z^3+z+2}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (z+1)^n c_n$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations, laurent-series

Given this equivalence:
$$\frac{1}{z^3+z+2}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (z+1)^n c_n$$
I must determine radius of convergence of the series and the coefficients $c_n$.

I'm definitely unsure of what to do here. I think that the radius of convergence is
$$R=\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}}}$$
Which of course I can't compute without having the coefficients. So I've looked at the sum of the series and evaluated it's roots, posing $t=z+1$:
$$\frac{1}{(z+1)(z-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\sqrt7)(z-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\sqrt7)}=\frac{1}{t(t-\frac{3}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\sqrt7)(t-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\sqrt7)}$$
And I think that it should be $|t|<2$, $|z+1|<2$.

I was looking for a recurrence law but I'm unsure and I haven't found out a lot but I'll show some of my tries. 
$$1=(z^3+z+2)\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (z+1)^n c_n=(t^3-3t^2+4)\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty t^n c_n=(?)= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty t^n (c_{n-3}-3c_{n-2}+4c_n)$$
I'm perplexed by that $-\infty$ from wich the series starts..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $w=z+1$, then 
$$
z^3+z+2=w^3-3w^2+3w+w=w(w^2-3w+4)
$$
so that there are two poles on the circle $|w|=2$, which gives you the radius of convergence for the power series in $w=z+1$.

Using a partial fraction decomposition on the factorization in linear factors and then the geometric series allows to find explicit formulas for the coefficients.

You get the $-\infty$ as lower index bound as a sign that the solution might not be a power series but a more general Laurent series. And indeed, as $w$ is a factor, the first term in the series has power $-1$.
$$
w\sum_{n=-1}^\infty c_nw^n=\frac1{w^2-3w+4}=\frac{i}{\sqrt7}\left(\frac{1}{w-\frac32+i\frac{\sqrt7}2}-\frac{1}{w-\frac32-i\frac{\sqrt7}2}\right)
$$

Comment: Thank you, do you have any suggestion on how to compute the coefficients?

Comment: Added a line on that. Using PFD and geometric series is pretty standard in this situation.

Comment: Perfect thank you very much!